# JOIN three tables in psql (SQL Query)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
UsersDevices: user_id, device_id
registration_posusercompany: company_id, user_id
registation_companyprofile: company_id, company_name
```

I know the `device_id` in `UsersDevices`, I now want to know the company_name to which the device belongs. For that the psuedo code goes like this:

```
--> Get user_id from UsersDevices where device_id = (I know this device_id)
--> Get company_id with that user_id from registration_posusercompany
--> Get company_name with that company_id
```

I was writing the subquery to do this, but subquery indeed is very slower compare to `JOIN`. How can I achieve this using JOIN. Thank you

Comment: I assume with `psql` you mean PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, sir. I mean PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select rc.company_name 
from UsersDevices as u 
   join registration_posusercompany as rp on rp.user_id = u.user_id 
   join registation_companyprofile as rc on rc.company_id = rp.company_id 
where u.device_id = yourvalue
```

Comment: where do I apply, `where device_id=something`?

Comment: Also, if you want to select the columns from the UsersDevices table only, then you can do "Select u.* from UsersDevices as u ....."

Comment: I want to select the coloumn from only `registration_companyprofile`. I want to get only `company_name`